# Dropping an item on a QComboBox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, drag-and-drop, pyqt5, qcombobox

Perhaps I am looking in the wrong place, or maybe I don't quite understand the concept fully; but I'm trying to find a working example where I can drop a text file on a `QComboBox`, and it will trigger a drop event that I can handle. I looking through the documentation, but there isn't a whole lot of information on the subject.

I have also searched around, but I haven't really found anything either. If I'm just not looking in the right place, please feel free to point me in the right direction.

Comment: let's say the text is: `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.`, What should happen in the QComboBox? Where do you get the text from?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is take a `.txt` from Windows File Explorer and drop it onto a `QComboBox` in a Python program. The idea is to have an event handler parse the file that was dropped onto the `QComboBox`, and add an entry into the `QComboBox` list. The parsed information has no meaning past being parsed, since it is not directly related to this. I just don't know where to start with this, and I wasn't able to really find any information on it.

Comment: That is, you would like the content to be printed when you drop a .txt file

Comment: Yes, just parsed and printed to console in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to overwrite the `dragEnterEvent` method to enable what type of elements are accepted and the `dropEvent` method where you will get information about the dragged element. But for this you must use `self.setAcceptDrops(True)` to enable that behavior

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class ComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QComboBox.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
         #print("formats: ", event.mimeData().formats())
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat("text/plain"):
            event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        url = QUrl(event.mimeData().text().strip())
        if url.isLocalFile():
            file = QFile(url.toLocalFile())
            if file.open(QFile.ReadOnly|QFile.Text):
                ts = QTextStream(file)
                while not ts.atEnd():
                    print(ts.readLine())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = ComboBox()
    w.addItems(["item {}".format(i) for i in range(10)])
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you need more information you can check the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html)