# How to enable QDropEvent when using a QT Designer (.ui) file in Python?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer, qcombobox

Using the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49100091/dropping-an-item-on-a-qcombobox) I have been able to get the `QDropEvent` to fire when not using a QT Designer (.ui) File; but I can't seem to get it working otherwise.

According to [this documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html#drag-and-drop-in-qt-quick) and [this example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-draganddrop-dropsite-example.html) it seems like I should only need to set `.setAcceptDrops()` as `True` for the `QComboBox` I want to accept the event, and implement the `dragEnterEvent` and `dropEvent` with all the necessary logic. I'm not really fluent in C++ so I only understand some of the example, but for the most part it seems straight forward.

The example I created for this doesn't throw any exception, and nothing seems to happen when I try to drop a text file from Windows Explorer onto the `cb1` `QComboBox`. I feel like I'm missing something simple, but I'm not sure what. Any ideas?

Using Python 3.7 and PyQt5

> main.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>269</width>
    <height>116</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="3" column="1">
     <widget class="QComboBox" name="cb4">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Fixed">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="1">
     <widget class="QComboBox" name="cb2">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Fixed">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="1">
     <widget class="QComboBox" name="cb3">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Fixed">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="1">
     <widget class="QComboBox" name="cb1">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Fixed">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="l1">
      <property name="text">
       <string>cb1</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="l2">
      <property name="text">
       <string>cb2</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="0">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="l3">
      <property name="text">
       <string>cb3</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="3" column="0">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="l4">
      <property name="text">
       <string>cb4</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

> QComboBoxDrop.py

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.Qt import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys

Ui_main = uic.loadUiType(r'main.ui')[0]


class MinExample(QMainWindow, Ui_main):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, flags = Qt.Window):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent, flags)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.cb1.addItems(["item {}".format(i) for i in range(5)])
        self.cb2.addItems(["item {}".format(i) for i in range(5)])
        self.cb3.addItems(["item {}".format(i) for i in range(5)])
        self.cb4.addItems(["item {}".format(i) for i in range(5)])

        self.cb1.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        print("dragEnterEvent Occurred")
        event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        print("dropEvent Occurred")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MinExample()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case that you already have a class that implements the logic that you want and want to use it in Qt Designer the correct option is to use the promotion, for it follow the steps that are in this answer and in step 4.1 change to the following:

[image]

On the other hand my solution of the old post does not work if the widget is a child of the window, in that case you must overwrite the dragMoveEvent method.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```
├── main.py
├── main.ui
└── qcomboboxdrop.py
```

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore, QtWidgets

Ui_main = uic.loadUiType(r'main.ui')[0]


class MinExample(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_main):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, flags = QtCore.Qt.Window):
        super(MinExample, self).__init__(parent, flags)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.cb1.addItems(["item {}".format(i) for i in range(5)])
        self.cb2.addItems(["item {}".format(i) for i in range(5)])
        self.cb3.addItems(["item {}".format(i) for i in range(5)])
        self.cb4.addItems(["item {}".format(i) for i in range(5)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MinExample()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>269</width>
    <height>148</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="3" column="1">
     <widget class="QComboBoxDrop" name="cb4">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Fixed">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="1">
     <widget class="QComboBoxDrop" name="cb2">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Fixed">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="1">
     <widget class="QComboBoxDrop" name="cb3">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Fixed">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="1">
     <widget class="QComboBoxDrop" name="cb1">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Fixed">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="l1">
      <property name="text">
       <string>cb1</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="l2">
      <property name="text">
       <string>cb2</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="0">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="l3">
      <property name="text">
       <string>cb3</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="3" column="0">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="l4">
      <property name="text">
       <string>cb4</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>QComboBoxDrop</class>
   <extends>QComboBox</extends>
   <header>qcomboboxdrop.h</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**qcomboboxdrop.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class QComboBoxDrop(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QComboBoxDrop, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
         # print("formats: ", event.mimeData().formats())
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat("text/plain"):
            event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat("text/plain"):
            event.acceptProposedAction()        

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        url =QtCore.QUrl(event.mimeData().text().strip())
        if url.isLocalFile():
            file = QtCore.QFile(url.toLocalFile())
            if file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly|QtCore.QFile.Text):
                ts = QtCore.QTextStream(file)
                while not ts.atEnd():
                    print(ts.readLine())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QComboBoxDrop()
    w.addItems(["item {}".format(i) for i in range(10)])
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The screenshot you shared has `qcomboboxdrop.h` listed for the header and again in the main.ui. In the case of python is this required? I thought that was mostly for C++ although I could be wrong.

Comment: @artomason The .h extension is irrelevant in python so if you do not want to see it change `qcomboboxdrop.h` to`qcomboboxdrop`. :-)

Comment: Thanks! Clear answer as always, and it seems to solve my secondary issue with figuring out which widget triggered the event since there will only be one. Speaking of which if there are multiple `QComboBox` elements, is there a straight forward way to determine which element triggered the event?

Comment: @artomason You could explain me better, to be able to differentiate elements must have a characteristic that allows to discriminate, for example you could use the objectName

Comment: Inside `dragEnterEvent` is there a way to tell which `QComboBox` fired the event? For example, I drag a file into `cb1` which triggers the `dragEnterEvent` and under `dragEnterEvent` I want to print the calling widget to console; in this case `cb1` or `self.cb1`

Comment: @artomason use `print(self)` or `print(self.objectName())`

Comment: @artomason I think that you have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) why do you want to discriminate what the combobox is?

Comment: In this case it is just to know, but say I have several `QComboBox` elements that all accept drops, but each combo box takes a different type of data, I could determine which action to take based on the element passing.

Comment: @artomason 
Okay, in your case use the objectName: `if self.objectName() == "cb1": ...`, If you are using Qt Designer it will establish it, but if you are going to add the QComboBox by code you will have to establish it.